# Integration Django and Bokeh - does not display plot

Tags: django, bokeh

I'm trying to integrate Django and Bokeh using the approach of [this article](https://hackernoon.com/integrating-bokeh-visualisations-into-django-projects-a1c01a16b67a)

Unfortunately, after writing the plot function it does not display anything.

**my views.py**

```
def homepage(request):
    x = [1,2,3,4,5]
    y = [1,2,3,4,5]

    plot = figure(title = 'Line Graph', x_axis_label='X-Ax',y_axis_label='Y-Ax',plot_width = 400,plot_height = 400)

    plot.line(x,y,line_width = 2)
    script,div = components(plot)
    return render(request,'repositorys.html',{'script': script,'div': div})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^repositorys/',views.homepage,name='repositorys'),
    url(r'^repositorys/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.repositorys_board, name='repositorys_board'),
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

]

**and repositorys.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href=”http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.4.0.min.css" rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css”>
        <link href=”http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.4.0.min.css" rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css”>
        <script src=”http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src=”http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
    {{ script | safe }}
    </head>

    <body>
    {{ div | safe }}
    </body>
</html>
```

My bokeh version is 1.4.0

Unfortunately, on my localhost nothing is displayed.

Comment: Did you check your browser's console? Often bokeh displays its errors via javascript in the browser. The console is reachable for example via ctrl-shift-i in Chrome. You might need to reload your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links that you added to head had an invalid character `”` instead of `"`

Replace it with these:

```
<link href= "http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.4.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.4.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
```

I could get the below graph simply by making the above changes.[image]